# Scraping invisible data from a website

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I want to parse data using [jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org/) from a website which contains data in tables which are in a "div" tag, when I inspect table data I can see the data in inspect element window, but if I see the page source the data is not present in the div tag.(They have taken a class called "invisible" for the entire div tag)
How to get that invisible data from the div tag

Comment: jSoup should be able to receive this data, i have used it before.   Can you give us an example HTML link i can look at the source?

Comment: Are the table contents loaded dynamically with JavaScript?